# How do I remove a xcode server from the report navigator?

Tags: xcode

I have two servers in my report navigator. One by IP address, the other by it's hostname. In reality they are the same server.
How do I get rid of the first one I created? (The one with the IP address)

[image]

Deleting / fnDelete doesn't work....
No option to remove on right click....
Is there something I can do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it !!!

XCode Servers are listed in XCode's preferences/accounts.
There you can delete / add servers